# ANDROID METAIO - I need to read a file in the phone memory from my app with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas, metaio

I am developing an application for ANDROID reality augmented with Metaio SDK.

I want to display a text from a file of my phone.
My javascript is positioned in the folder ASSETS

I need a JavaScript function that reads a text file from the phone memory.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you show us anything that you have tried so far ?

Comment: Please show what you have tried, else go pay someone to do your code for you!

Comment: Yes, I put the script:

Comment: What are you using? Apache Cordova/phonegap and Metaio's AREL?

Answer (score 0):

```
//create an HTML5 Canvas
canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.width = 1000;

canvas.height = 842;

//get a 2D context

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

//draw transparent background

context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 255)";

context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

//draw text
context.fillStyle = "black";

context.font = 'bold 40pt Calibri';

var maxWidth = 1000;

var lineHeight = 50;

var x = (canvas.width - maxWidth) / 2;

var y = 60;

var text;

**text = getTextFile();**

context.fillText(text , x, y);

//creat image data from the canvas

var newImageData = canvas.toDataURL();

return new arel.Image(newImageData);
```

Comment: I need to implements the function  ------- text = getTextFile(); --------